# JCrop Check if Region Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

Can anybody tell me how to check if an area has been selected for cropping in JCrop?

Was hoping for a boolean function in the API but I see no such thing. I tried using the the updatecoords function but x, y, w, and h, are set even when a selection is not chosen.

Here's my instantiation:

```
var jcrop_api;
$('#profile_crop').Jcrop({onSelect: updateCoords, setSelect: [0, 542, 671, 0], boxWidth: 542, boxHeight: 671, aspectRatio: 542/671},
    function() {
         jcrop_api = this; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to manually detect when there is a selection, so use the 
onRelease handler. From the API:

```
var jcrop_api;
var selected;
$('#profile_crop').Jcrop({onSelect: showCoords, onRelease: releaseCoords, setSelect: [0, 542, 671, 0], boxWidth: 542, boxHeight: 671, aspectRatio: 542/671},
  function() {
    jcrop_api = this; 
  }
);

function showCoords(c){
  selected = true;
  // variables can be accessed here as
  // c.x, c.y, c.x2, c.y2, c.w, c.h
};

function releaseCoords(c){
  selected = false;
  // variables can be accessed here as
  // c.x, c.y, c.x2, c.y2, c.w, c.h
};
```

Le me know if I didn't answer your question!